# Browse Server Folders in Client

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement for an admin user to set up an export directory on the web server, or relative to the web server using a UNC.  Is there anything already out there that I can use for this, or must I recurs a limited directories and populate a home-rolled directory browser on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this today ...a JQuery File Tree plugin. The link includes "connector scripts" in a number of server side languages including asp.net:

http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook.php?article=58

Looks awesome (and well documented) but I have not tried. I would love to hear feedback if anyone has...

Answer (score 0):

Every solution to this problem I have seen is a home-rolled implementation of directory browsing.

When attaching a database on a SQL server, Microsoft uses a "custom" treeview to show drives/folders/files available to be attached.

Also, on DotNetNuke (an Open Source ASP.NET Content Management System) they have a home-rolled implementation as well for uploading files to Portal Folders...